# Why it's a convention to import pandas as pd?

Tags: python, pandas

I see that in the pandas documentation they recommend importing pandas as:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I can see some sense in doing that for when you are using pandas in an interactive context (as with a ipython/jupyter notebook), but I've seen it in production code and in widespread libraries (like Bokeh: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/search?p=2&q=pd&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93). Is there a reason for that apart from convention?

Comment: And less typing as well as the matter of habit, which is not to forget.

Comment: `Why it's a convention` is a weird kind of question - for me the term `convention` implies that there is no deep explanation. A convention is something people agreed upon. They could have agreed on something else as well.

Comment: My theory: Because data scientists generally (generally!) don't have years of experience writing and maintaining production software. Therefore, quite understandably, they think it's a good idea to shorten "pandas" to "pd" and save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are `built-in` methods in python which overlap with the pandas methods. Like `map(), all(), any(), filter(), max(), min()` and many others. In order to avoid the confusion that these methods used are from pandas or built-in. It is always better to import pandas as `import pandas as pd` and call the pandas methods using the `pd` prefix.

There might be other libraries which have the same method names, so to avoid `overriding` we use the prefix part.

Comment: How does `as pd` part help? you could just write `pandas.min` instead of `pd.min`

Comment: If you do not import `as pd`, you still have to qualify the methods (with `pandas.` instead of `pd.`) and hence do not have the problem you claim the `as pd` avoids.